# Booting Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB stick goes dark and freezes after selecting boot option

Tags: system-installation, usb

I have tried to boot from a USB drive using three different programs, LinuxLive USB creator, Universal USB creator, and UNetBootin. I am using a Dell Latitude E5410 running Windows 7 and am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.

Each time I select boot from USB device, I get to a menu with options to try Ubuntu without installing, boot into Ubuntu, and install on Hard Disk. No matter which option I choose my screen goes to a not-quite-black color and nothing happens. I have to disconnect my laptop from its power source to restart it.

I was wondering if there might be a problem with my USB stick (Sandisk Cruzer 8GB). I tried using the *check drive for errors* option from **My Computer > Removable Disk (F:) > Properties > Tools** but it said no error found. Also, later I tried another USB stick and had the same problem.

It was suggested to me that this might be a problem with my video card. My video card is an Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator HD (Core i5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. This was the solution:

1. Hit <kbd>tab</kbd> when you get to the menu that comes up when you boot from it
2. look for the end of the string, before `--`
3. remove the `quiet` and `splash` parameters and add `nomodeset xforcevesa` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not, but try pendrivelinux to make the bootable usb, I tried it and could install ubuntu fine, even with a 2 GB microsd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this program:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

In step 3: **specify Format Drive**

In step 4: **specify 0 MB**

Comment: No such luck. Same result as always :( I'm going to give up and try a CD-ROM.

Comment: Even so I think it's a problem USB drive... It is interesting to see the results with DVD drive.